# Is it possible to use SIM card cryptographic functions?

Tags: android, api, cryptography, sim-card

All smartcards have embedded crypto capabilities and computation power.

Is is possible to take advantage of this with developed android application? For example, would I be able to sign a file using the public/private key stored on the SIM.

I heard about some standards and norms and initiatives (ETSI-MSS, Mobile PKI) but I do not see any application of such architecture.

Do someone has some clue on this?

Comment: It seems that phone SIM cards have very limited cryptography-related functionality. I.e. they are not smartcards as we know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>My understanding is that SIM cards do not use standard crypto. The handle certains kinds of authentication and crypto for the network. Given the quality of say A3/5, I'm not sure you would want to. I doubt you can get AES or reven basic RSA out of them</strike>

Actually the above statement is somewhat incorrect: apparently there is work either to get SIM cards to have  this functionality or to write generic libraries for exposing it. I cannot,however, for the life of me remember the article I read this in.

This appears at least to be a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364030/980922

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot access the SIM card directly in Android. All access to telephony-related services takes place in the [TelephonyManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and there is no API exposed to doing and cryptographic operations in the SIM.